# PostgreSQL ALTER SEQUENCE using psycopg2 in django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to alter sequence of id field in my table using psycopg. This is works fine on my local server, but not working on production. I am not getting exceptions, the sequence is just not restarting.

```
def alter_sequence(last_id):
    try:
        dbname = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
        user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
        host = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
        password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
        port = settings.DATABASES['default']['PORT']
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=dbname,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port,
        )
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE "gs_requests_id_seq" RESTART WITH {}'.format(last_id))
        connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    pass
```

I double-checked the database settings - its correct. Other database operations, performed by django ORM with this settings is works fine.

I think, this is not enough information about my project settings but dont know what information I need to specify. I have postgres 9.6 on my local computer and 10.1 on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('ALTER SEQUENCE gs_requests_id_seq RESTART WITH {};'.format(last_id))
```

Try this!! it will worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I found source of the problem. I didn't commit:

connection.commit()